# iOS app with preloaded images

Tags: ios, image, performance

I'm creating an iOS app with some preloaded data which includes images, it will have between 150 and 200 images. This images are not downloaded from a server, since the app won't connect to the internet.

I'm wondering about if saving the images locally can cause any problem, what is the max size that I can use to store them? Can this affect the app's performance? Anything else that I should be aware of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over the air cellular maximum download is now 100MB since the iOS 7 launch.

Your maximum app size is 2GB with a maximum binary size of 60MB. With 200 images I don't think you'll hit the 2GB mark, so long as you use the proper compression techniques.

The only thing that would affect your app's performance is the way the images are presented. If they're really large images, 10+ MB you'll most likely hit memory problems in older devices and if you go larger, memory problems in newer devices. There's plenty of techniques like tiling in a scroll view to get around these problems but it requires you splice up your images and create multiple resolution versions of the image.

Comment: I can give an estimation, we have a universal app with 600-700 "random" images (mixed, some of them are in full size, some of them smaller than the actual screen), and the _ipa_ file is about 180 MB (no retina support).

Answer (score 1):

If your app is greater than 50MB (at the time of writing) because of the images being included then users will need WiFi to install it.

Other than that, your performance concerns should be around how many of the images you will have loaded into memory at any one time and how you can reduce that number.